# Usando else dentro do foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Pessoal tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php 
  $string = $_POST['search'];
  foreach($results['results']['collection1'] as $collection) {
    if(stristr($collection['prod']['text'],$string) !== false) {
      echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-sm-6'><img src='" . $collection['img']['src'] . "'><br />"; 
      echo "<a target='_blank' href='" . $collection['prod']['href'] . "'>" . $collection['prod']['text'] . "</a><br />". $collection['valor'] . "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "Nada encontrado";
    }
  }
```

O problema que quando o echo do else entra em ação o resultado é este:

> Nada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada encontradoNada....

O ideal é aparecer apenas uma vez o `Nada encontrado`.

Comment: Tenta colocar `;` depois do último `}`, e colocar um `break` depois de cada retorno (do `if` e do `else`)... No caso do `else` fica `else {  echo "Nada encontrado"; break; }`

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo do que teria em `$results['results']['collection1']`?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, se, pelo menos uma vez, o conteúdo do `if` for verdadeiro, o `"Nada encontrado"` não deve aparecer. Crie uma variável para controlar isto e teste se encontrou algo fora do loop:

```
<?php 
  $string = $_POST['search'];
  $encontrado = false;
  foreach($results['results']['collection1'] as $collection) {
    if(stristr($collection['prod']['text'],$string) !== false) {
      echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-sm-6'><img src='" . $collection['img']['src'] . "'><br />"; 
      echo "<a target='_blank' href='" . $collection['prod']['href'] . "'>" . $collection['prod']['text'] . "</a><br />". $collection['valor'] . "</div>";
      $encontrado = true;
    }
  }
  if (!$encontrado) {
    echo "Nada encontrado";
  }
```

Deste modo somente se nada for encontrado, o texto será exibido, uma única vez.